# TensorFlow operations with GPU support

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

Is there a way (or maybe a list?) to determine all the tensorflow operations which offer GPU support?
Right now, it is a trial and error process for me - I try to place a group of operations on GPU. If it works, sweet. If not, try somewhere else.

This is the only thing relevant (but not helpful) I have found so far: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems there's no built-in way to get an exact list or even check this for a specific op. As mentioned in the issue above, the dispatching is done in the native C++ code: a particular operation can be assigned to GPU if a corresponding kernel has been registered to `DEVICE_GPU`.

I think the easiest way for you is to `grep "REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER" -r tensorflow` the tensorflow source base to get a list of matched operations, which will look something [like this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER&type=).

But remember that even with `REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER` specification, there's no guarantee an op will be performed on a GPU. For example, 32-bit int `Add` is assigned on CPU regardless of the existing kernel.